# Must be used before declaration

Tags: c#, oop, console

I'm trying to make a console game, and I have a problem with the following code (and future code)

```html
Node n1 = new Node("You Are in a Snowy biome, you notice your Crashed Vehicle behind you.", map1, n9, n2, null, n3, null, null, "You Notice Your Crashed Vehicle, it is Beyond use now.", null);

Node n2 = new Node("You Notice a Metal Lamp Post Standing Tall, the Light is on.", map2, n8, n4, null, n1, "You Move Past the Lamp Post.", null, "You see Part of your Crashed Vehicle, it was Pretty Long.", "This was where you Crashed.");

Node n3 = new Node("You Notice a Box with a Red Plus Sign on it.", map3, n10, n1, null, null, "You Walk Towards the box and open the Lid...", ItemN3.GetItem());

Node n4 = new Node(null, map4, n7, n5, null, n2, null, null, "A huge Wall of Fire Blocks the whole of the South.", "You Move back To the Lamp Post.");

Node n5 = new Node("You See A massive hole to the East.", map5, n6, null, null, n4, "You See the hole, Around 54ft Deep.", null, "The Wall of Fire Continues.", null);
```

The Nodes take these Params:

[image]

But I have errors telling me I cant use a `Node` before it is declared, but when I move it above the error, I get the same error on one of the other nodes further down. So its just an infinite loop of errors.
I have no idea how I can fix this. If possible, please can someone help?

Comment: My advice: stop doing everything in the constructor. Assign properties after it's constructed, or introduce a method to accept neighbours.

Comment: @Llama So  you want me to make a seperate method for creating the node?

Comment: @Isparia OP is referencing n9, n2, and n3 in the constructor of n1. In n2 they're referencing n1.

Comment: @Llama You are right It Will work if i Construct the Object as empty then i run a method which takes All the Params. Thank Youu :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you've got a chicken and egg situation going on. I'll simplify your example with this class:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(Node neighbour)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you're effectively doing this:

```
Node n1 = new Node(n2);
Node n2 = new Node(n1);
```

Obviously this won't work, since an object needs to be initialized before it can be used. You could create the node and then assign properties afterwards:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Neighbour {get;set;}
}
```

And then initialize them like this:

```
Node n1 = new Node();
Node n2 = new Node();
n1.Neighbour = n2;
n2.Neighbour = n1;
```

If your directions are always cardinal, you could potentially create a 2d array (`Node[,]`) and then automatically loop through assigning neighbours after you've initialized all the nodes.

Comment: This is exactly what i have done Now. Thank you so much this took me sooooo long to try figure out. :)))

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying your code, here's the problem:

```
Node n1 = new Node(n2);

Node n2 = new Node(n8);
```

You try to use n2 before you have declared or initialized it.

Instead, have a method or property that does the assignment, e.g.

```
public class Node
{
    public void Next(Node n) ...
}

Node n1 = new Node();    
Node n2 = new Node();
n1.Next(n2);
```